# specify a region for pytrends Google Trends API

Tags: python, google-trends

Hello I am using pytrends, I would like to search for keywords only in a specific region/city (for example Ile-de-France or Paris) instead of just France. 
Is it possible with pytrends or another API ?

Answer (score 3):

with `pytrends` you can specify province in `geo=*` by entering `geo=FR-J` for Île-de-France province(Paris)

Comment: just in google trends checked the url for geo attribute, e.g https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=FR&q=%2Fm%2F025rw19 there you can see map and select any region of France and the url would change with geo value for selected province. For sure there is a better way to find a region but I don't know any :)